# How to find bean declaration from interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

Consider the following interface in spring boot

```
public interface SecurityFilterChain {

    boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request);

    List<Filter> getFilters();

}
```

This `SecurityFilterChain` is registered in `SecurityFilterChainConfiguration` class like below;

```
@Bean
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());
    http.formLogin(withDefaults());
    http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```

The question is that given `SecurityFilterChain` interface, how can I find that this bean is actually registered in `defaultSecurityFilterChain` method?

There seems to be no obvious way to find the bean declaration unless you know all your beans by heart.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to check if you can find such information from its `BeanDefinition`.

Given a bean type , you can get its bean name from `ApplicationContext`:

```java
String[] beanNames = context.getBeanNamesForType(SecurityFilterChain.class);
```

One of bean name should be `defaultSecurityFilterChain`. Then given a bean name , you can get its `BeanDefinition` by :

```java
 BeanDefinition bd = context.getBeanDefinition("defaultSecurityFilterChain");
```

`BeanDefinition` has an method `getResourceDescription()` to return the description of the resource that this bean came from :

```
bd.getResourceDescription();
```

which will print out :

> class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$**SecurityFilterChainConfiguration**.class]